# Delete a line that contain a word

Tags: c++

i am trying to remove a line that contain a specific word from text file
but it's not working

```
void deleteline()
{
    string line, deletecontact;
    cout << "Plase enter the contact (name or number) to delete:";
    cin >> deletecontact;
    ifstream file;
    ofstream outfile;
    file.open("data.txt");
    outfile.open("newM.txt");
    while (getline(file, line)) {
        if (line != deletecontact) {
            outfile << line << endl;
        }
    }
    outfile.close();
    file.close();
    remove("movieList.txt");
    rename("newM.txt", "data.txt");
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: [It doesn't work](http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/)?

Comment: `remove("movieList.txt");` Shouldn't that be `remove("data.txt");`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You remove lines only if they are equal (i.e. `line != deleteContact`). If you want to remove lines that, as you mentioned, only contain this word, you should write something like the following:

```cpp
if (strstr(line.c_str(), deleteContact.c_str()) == nullptr) ...
```

Comment: See also std::string::find http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/

Comment: Use `std::search` for a case-insensitive search. `strstr` is more of a 'C' function.

Comment: Have you used the debugger and looked into `line` and `deletecontact`? Maybe it's an encoding issue...

Comment: sorry it's worked it was my fault i was checking other file